# How to get reviews history

Tags: api, upsource

I'm using the Upsource API to get the revisions and reviews.
Does anyone know which method to use to get the reviews summary?

[Review Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctNv4.png)

I've tried getReviewSummaryChanges, getReviewSummaryDiscussions, but I didn't get what I needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try other methods as described in the documentation:
https://upsource.evolutiongaming.com/~api_doc/reference/index.html

Try POST with "getFeed" method to get complete set of changes happening to a review : including "addedRevisions":

https://upsource-host/~rpc/getFeed

```
{ 
    "limit": 20,
    "type": 2,
    "projectId":"myproject",
    "reviewId":"MYPROJECT-CR-123"
}
```